# Error installing R package Rmpfr - Error in rematchDefinition

Tags: r, cran

I'm running RStudio 1.1.419 on linux mint, and trying to install the CRAN package Rmpfr for arbitrary precision number support.

As per other questions I've installed:

```
sudo apt-get install libmpfr-dev
```

Then I've restarted RStudio, and tried installing the Rmpfr package again. The installation fails with the following error which I don't see on stack overflow or google.

```
** preparing package for lazy loading
Creating a generic function for ‘factorial’ from package ‘base’ in package ‘Rmpfr’
Creating a generic function for ‘quantile’ from package ‘stats’ in package ‘Rmpfr’
Creating a generic function for ‘mean’ from package ‘base’ in package ‘Rmpfr’
Creating a generic function for ‘median’ from package ‘stats’ in package ‘Rmpfr’
Error in rematchDefinition(definition, fdef, mnames, fnames, signature) : 
  methods can add arguments to the generic ‘median’ only if '...' is an argument to the generic
Error : unable to load R code in package ‘Rmpfr’
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘Rmpfr’
* removing ‘/home/davidparks21/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/Rmpfr’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘Rmpfr’ had non-zero exit status
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a nifty one.

`stats::median` has changed - you are still using R 3.2, in which case:

```
> stats::median
function (x, na.rm = FALSE) 
UseMethod("median")
<bytecode: 0x0000000008473270>
<environment: namespace:stats>
```

Whereas now, we have:

```
> stats::median
function (x, na.rm = FALSE, ...) 
UseMethod("median")
<bytecode: 0x000000001071c050>
<environment: namespace:stats>
```

Rmpfr has been updated recently, see here for reference:
https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/R/Summary.R?view=markup&revision=272&root=rmpfr

You should **upgrade R** if you want to use the latest version of Rmpfr.

Comment: I am also asking the package author if he thinks the dependency in the DESCRIPTION file should be updated

Comment: Worked like a charm. Incidentally, I was using the version of R that is installed by default with Ubuntu/Linux mint. I had to follow these procedures to update to the latest version of R: https://www.r-bloggers.com/how-to-install-r-on-linux-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus/

Comment: I will update the R version dependency to `>= 3.3.0` ... but not re-release `Rmpfr` just because of that, of course.  Good advice indeed, @RolandASc

Comment: @RolandASc it seems the stats::median has not been updated in R version 3.3.2.  `stats::median
function (x, na.rm = FALSE) 
UseMethod("median")
<bytecode: 0x2b4e820>`

Comment: Another way is to install the old version of `Rmpfr`, such as 0.6.1,  https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/Rmpfr/Rmpfr_0.6-1.tar.gz .